# Is it possible to redirect HTTPS to HTTPS with nginx?

Tags: nginx, ssl

I have the following issue.
I created this danish website flaatinfo.dk that is also accessible by flåtinfo.dk.

The domain manager gave me a certificate for flaatinfo.dk but said that they could not generate one for flåtinfo.dk because it contains a special character.

Is there a way (in nginx setup) that I can redirect all HTTPS requests from flåtinfo.dk to flaatinfo.dk??

HTTP redirects seem to work fine but if I try to redirect HTTPS like this I get cert error in browser:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name flåtinfo.dk www.flåtinfo.dk;
    return 301 https://flaatinfo.dk$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if what you are trying to do is possible. If you try to access a https site that doesn't have a cert you will get an error in browser.

Comment: No, if you don't have a (valid) certificate for domainname X, you can't receive https://X requests and thus can't redirect them. Letsencrypt says they have supported 'internationalized' domainnames (meaning non-English) since 2016, though I can't confirm personally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`www.flåtinfo.dk` is an internationalized domain name (IDN).

According to [NGINX documentation for internationalized names](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#idn):

> domain names (IDNs) should be specified using an ASCII (Punycode)
> representation in the `server_name` directive

So you should specify it in NGINX configuration as `xn--fltinfo-fxa.dk`.

As for why your plain HTTP redirect worked anyway, it's probably because it didn't match any other domain so NGINX had to eventually choose it as default.

> I get cert error in browser

Naturally, since you don't have a TLS certificate for your IDN, browsers will issue warnings. You need to get a TLS certificate for IDN to get rid of the warning. Let's Encrypt supports issuing certs for IDNs and is free of charge.

Comment: so there is no way to redirect flåtinfo.dk to flaatinfo.dk without issuing a new IDN certificate for flåtinfo.dk, right?

Comment: Yep. Without proper certificate the redirect will always give a browser warning.